# Target WSGI script '/home/rajeshkumarponnu/Documents/OFFICE/IAB_PROJECT/iab_pro/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module

Tags: python-3.x, apache, django-rest-framework, mod-wsgi, django-wsgi

I am struggling to deploy the django rest api in apache with wsgi and getting 500 error. Here is my files, please suggest/help me where i am wrong.

Even so many facing same issues and i refered that also..but i could not able fix this error.

**wsgi.py:**

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'iab_pro.settings')
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**000-default.conf:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    ServerName 192.0.18.111
    ServerAdmin rajeshkumar.ponnusamy@indegene.com
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/rajeshkumarponnu/Documents/OFFICE/IAB_PROJECT/iab_pro/wsgi.py
    <Directory /home/rajeshkumarponnu/Documents/OFFICE/IAB_PROJECT/iab_pro/>
    <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
    </Files>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
     WSGIDaemonProcess IAB_PROJECT python-path=/home/rajeshkumarponnu/Documents/OFFICE/IAB_PROJECT python-home=/home/rajeshkumarponnu/Documents/OFFICE/venv_iab

     WSGIProcessGroup IAB_PROJECT
</VirtualHost>
```

**apache error log**

```
[Fri Jan 10 12:14:57.407703 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 17242:tid 140717350381312] [remote 192.0.18.111:49210] mod_wsgi (pid=17242): Target WSGI script '/home/rajeshkumarponnu/Documents/OFFICE/IAB_PROJECT/iab_pro/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri Jan 10 12:14:57.407764 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 17242:tid 140717350381312] [remote 192.0.18.111:49210] mod_wsgi (pid=17242): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/rajeshkumarponnu/Documents/OFFICE/IAB_PROJECT/iab_pro/wsgi.py'.
[Fri Jan 10 12:14:57.408932 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 17242:tid 140717350381312] [remote 192.0.18.111:49210] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Jan 10 12:14:57.408972 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 17242:tid 140717350381312] [remote 192.0.18.111:49210]   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/config.py", line 565, in configure
[Fri Jan 10 12:14:57.408978 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 17242:tid 140717350381312] [remote 192.0.18.111:49210]     handler = self.configure_handler(handlers[name])
[Fri Jan 10 12:14:57.408985 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 17242:tid 140717350381312] [remote 192.0.18.111:49210]   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/config.py", line 738, in configure_handler
[Fri Jan 10 12:14:57.408989 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 17242:tid 140717350381312] [remote 192.0.18.111:49210]     result = factory(**kwargs)
[Fri Jan 10 12:14:57.408995 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 17242:tid 140717350381312] [remote 192.0.18.111:49210]   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1032, in __init__
[Fri Jan 10 12:14:57.408999 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 17242:tid 140717350381312] [remote 192.0.18.111:49210]     StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
[Fri Jan 10 12:14:57.409007 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 17242:tid 140717350381312] [remote 192.0.18.111:49210]   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1061, in _open
[Fri Jan 10 12:14:57.409011 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 17242:tid 140717350381312] [remote 192.0.18.111:49210]     return open(self.baseFilename, self.mode, encoding=self.encoding)
[Fri Jan 10 12:14:57.409028 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 17242:tid 140717350381312] [remote 192.0.18.111:49210] FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/logs/error.log'
[Fri Jan 10 12:14:57.409037 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 17242:tid 140717350381312] [remote 192.0.18.111:49210]
[Fri Jan 10 12:14:57.409041 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 17242:tid 140717350381312] [remote 192.0.18.111:49210] During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
[Fri Jan 10 12:14:57.409044 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 17242:tid 140717350381312] [remote 192.0.18.111:49210]
[Fri Jan 10 12:14:57.409050 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 17242:tid 140717350381312] [remote 192.0.18.111:49210] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Jan 10 12:14:57.409078 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 17242:tid 140717350381312] [remote 192.0.18.111:49210]   File "/home/rajeshkumarponnu/Documents/OFFICE/IAB_PROJECT/iab_pro/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Fri Jan 10 12:14:57.409083 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 17242:tid 140717350381312] [remote 192.0.18.111:49210]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Fri Jan 10 12:14:57.409092 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 17242:tid 140717350381312] [remote 192.0.18.111:49210]   File "/home/rajeshkumarponnu/Documents/OFFICE/venv_iab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
[Fri Jan 10 12:14:57.409096 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 17242:tid 140717350381312] [remote 192.0.18.111:49210]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Fri Jan 10 12:14:57.409102 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 17242:tid 140717350381312] [remote 192.0.18.111:49210]   File "/home/rajeshkumarponnu/Documents/OFFICE/venv_iab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
[Fri Jan 10 12:14:57.409114 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 17242:tid 140717350381312] [remote 192.0.18.111:49210]     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
[Fri Jan 10 12:14:57.409121 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 17242:tid 140717350381312] [remote 192.0.18.111:49210]   File "/home/rajeshkumarponnu/Documents/OFFICE/venv_iab/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 75, in configure_logging
[Fri Jan 10 12:14:57.409125 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 17242:tid 140717350381312] [remote 192.0.18.111:49210]     logging_config_func(logging_settings)
[Fri Jan 10 12:14:57.409131 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 17242:tid 140717350381312] [remote 192.0.18.111:49210]   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/config.py", line 802, in dictConfig
[Fri Jan 10 12:14:57.409135 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 17242:tid 140717350381312] [remote 192.0.18.111:49210]     dictConfigClass(config).configure()
[Fri Jan 10 12:14:57.409140 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 17242:tid 140717350381312] [remote 192.0.18.111:49210]   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/config.py", line 573, in configure
[Fri Jan 10 12:14:57.409144 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 17242:tid 140717350381312] [remote 192.0.18.111:49210]     '%r: %s' % (name, e))
[Fri Jan 10 12:14:57.409155 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 17242:tid 140717350381312] [remote 192.0.18.111:49210] ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'file': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/logs/error.log'
```

I am using python3.6 in my system, so installed

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
```

I have tried with www-data:www-data for venev folder and as well as project folder (IAB_PROJECT) and gave 777 permission for all folders. But still same error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `WSGIScriptAlias / /home/rajeshkumarponnu/Documents/OFFICE/IAB_PROJECT/iab_pro/wsgi.py`
Is the extra leading / required here?

Comment: Yes..Thats is needed

Answer (score 0):

This [tutorial](https://blog.learningdollars.com/2020/01/16/how-to-host-a-django-api-using-mod-wsgi-serving-a-react-frontend-on-an-apache-server-on/) gives a concise walkthrough on how to go about running a Django Api on an apache server, maybe it'll give you a hint on how to solve the problem. Good luck.